# Should e.which be checked before e.keyCode or vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keycode

Say that I am not using jQuery, and want to support IE8 along with the other mainstream browsers.

In order to normalize events, I am following this pattern:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    
    var code;
    
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    
    code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    // More stuff here...
};
```

However, I suspect that if I changed the order of my `e.which` vs `e.keyCode` check, like so...

```
code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

...then my code *might* act differently across browsers.

1. Question: Does the order matter? Is one order "better" than the
   other?
2. Bonus: If I'm only supporting IE8 and up, does `e.charCode` matter?
3. Another bonus: Should I use `var e = window.event` or just `e = window.event`?

Comment: How about `code = e.which || e.keyCode` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will use that style going forward.

Comment: for what browsers are "which" used that don't suppport "keyCode"?

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure, and despite searching I haven't been able to figure that out. Are you implying that e.keyCode "came first," and thus any browser that supports e.which must also support e.keyCode?

Comment: @Jackson: no, i'm saying i never use which. i think only netscape NEEDED it, and it's been a while since i targeted netscape...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Yes, the order matters.**

The order you should use is indeed:

```
code = e.which || e.keyCode;
```

This is because most browsers support `e.which` ([IE<9 excluded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), of course). This way, any browser (IE>=9 and FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, etc.) that supports `e.which` will use it, and those that don't will use `e.keyCode`.

Should you switch the order to:

```
code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

You'll get `e.keyCode` for virtually every browser (instead of `e.which`) which will tell you the key that was pressed but not the resulting character (which I suspect is not what you want).

**2. No, e.charCode does not matter.**

Browser support for e.charCode [is spotty at best](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). Even [IE9 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it's for compatibiity only. Most popular modern browsers return `undefined` or `0` (or ASCII, or Extended ASCII, if you're lucky and even then it's only on `keypress`).

Additional reading for both **1** and **2** should probably be done at:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#link4
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Should you wish to play around with key events, [I made a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/NXQBS/) to report the [relevant] properties of the event parameter when you type in the sole input field.

**3. You should definitely use `var e = window.event;`.**

If you don't use `var`, you're effectively declaring `window.e = window.event` which is silly. Use `var` to keep `e` defined in the scope of your handler.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answers! The quirksmode links seem kind of outdated, but the fiddle is excellent; I'll keep that bookmarked.